# DatabaseMetaData.getTables returns trace_xe_action_map trace_xe_event_map

Tags: java, jdbc, database-metadata

`trace_xe_action_map` and `trace_xe_event_map` - what are those and where are they? I don't want to return those. How to change the parameters?

Currently I am using:

```
databaseMetadata.getTables(null, null, null, {"TABLE"} );
```

Comment: Did you Google before asking the question? Because the first Google result for trace_xe_action_map gives a hint...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? If those are system tables, I'm pretty sure they are documented in the manual for your database.

Comment: MSDN says "Contains one row for each Extended Events action that is mapped to a SQL Trace column ID. This table is stored in the master database, in the sys schema."  But I don't see it in the master database.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012. I believes those are system tables. The problem is I don't want my java code return those. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using MS SQL 2012 (or possibly later, but I haven't tried those). Try entering a schema name e.g:

```
ResultSet tableRS = dbMeta.getTables(null, "dbo", null, new String[] {"TABLE"});
```

as those tables have moved to sys.trace_xe...

Answer (score 0):

By default all the tables in MS SQL are created in "dbo" default schema. So, to retrieve tables from meta data we have to mention the schema name.
Note : if schema name is not mentioned all the tables will be returned.

```
ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getTables(dbName, schemaName, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
```